# Finding a Connectable Game Server In a Local Network

Tags: c#, sockets

**Description:**

I'm trying to make a auto server finder (like minecraft local game finder) for a game that connects to "player 2" through Socket.
Tested to do the job this way but it does not work properly:

```
var result = socket.BeginConnect(endpoint, null, null);
bool success = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeout, true);
```

---

**The Problem:**

I can't set timeout for `Socket.Connect()` which tries to find the local server inside of a `for`. testing 255 possible IPs takes at least 55 seconds which is a long time to do a simple server finding task.

---

**Question:**

What can i do for finding the server (expect Pinging) on a specific port (in this case 1234)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A for loop is generally a bad idea. I would recommend using the broadcast options.

You can find an example of this here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tst0kwb1(v=vs.110).aspx

The server then sends a response to the client who did the broadcast. After that you can establish a 'normal' connection